# Python Fuzzywuzzy matching with process and add info from comparing dataframe

Tags: python, string-matching, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to match names from two dataframes (in the name columns) using fuzzywuzzy with process. The result should be df1(dfdum) with the best matching name from df2(dfpep) and the similarity score. This is going very well with the code below but besides the matching name and score I want to append more columns from df2 to df1 in the result. The dates of birth and countries of residence from df2 belonging to the matching name should also be added to df1. I cannot simply merge on names because there are duplicates.

Can anyone help me to amend the code so that i can add the extra info from the matching names from df2? I thus want to add two extra columns to df1 with relating information from the matching name from df2.

```
pep_name = []
sim_name = []
for i in dfdum.NAME:
        ratio = process.extract(i, dfpep.NAME, limit=1,scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio)
        pep_name.append(ratio[0][0])
        sim_name.append(ratio[0][1])
dfdum['pep_name'] = pd.Series(pep_name)
dfdum['sim_name'] = pd.Series(sim_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the index of the best match in dfpep.NAME, and use that to retrieve the corresponding values of the other two columns.

This code (with some mock data) should give you the desired result; it assumes that dfpep.NAME has only unique values, though.

Please note that I'm far from a pandas expert so this solution is by no means the fastest or most elegant, but it should do the job :)

Also, I feel like there should be a way to do this without the for loop; maybe someone here has an idea for that.

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process, fuzz

dfdum = pd.DataFrame(["Johnny", "Peter", "Ben"])
dfdum.columns = ["NAME"]

dfpep = pd.DataFrame(["Pete", "John", "Bennie"])
dfpep.columns = ["NAME"]

dfpep["dob"] = pd.Series(["1990", "1991", "1992"])
dfpep["cor"] = pd.Series(["USA", "UK", "Germany"])

pep_name = []
sim_name = []
dob = []
cor = []

for i in dfdum.NAME:
    ratio = process.extract(i, dfpep.NAME, limit=1, scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio)
    pep_name.append(ratio[0][0])
    sim_name.append(ratio[0][1])

    j = dfpep.index[dfpep.NAME == ratio[0][0]].tolist()[0]

    dob.append(dfpep['dob'][j])
    cor.append(dfpep['cor'][j])

dfdum['pep_name'] = pd.Series(pep_name)
dfdum['sim_name'] = pd.Series(sim_name)
dfdum['dob'] = pd.Series(dob)
dfdum['cor'] = pd.Series(cor)

print(dfdum)
```